# Generate random numbers that only occur once in JMeter

Tags: testing, random, jmeter, numbers, unique

I want to generate an array of **random numbers that only occur once** for multiple inputs in JMeter. For example for a range of 1-100:

`"age": ${__Random(1,101)},
"weight": ${__Random(1,101)},
"height": ${__Random(1,101)}`

There is a chance that two of the variables will have the same value, how could I avoid such incident?

Comment: Those wouldn't be random numbers any more.
You can use an BeanShell Processor and a simple if-condition to recalculate your variables if they are taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **unique** random number you will need to add [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) using [ThreadLocalRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) with the following code

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
int[] array = ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(0, 100).distinct().limit(3).toArray();
vars.put("age", String.valueOf(array[0]));
vars.put("weight", String.valueOf(array[1]));
vars.put("height", String.valueOf(array[2]));
```

And then call the parameters in request:

```
"age": ${age},
"weight": ${weight},
"height": ${height}
```

Comment: @GeorgiosMourtzounis you welcome, this can be flexible with changing `3` in limit and adding more lines to get more unique number, and also increasing `100` to allow bigger numbers

Answer (score 0):

SuperQA${__Random(4,ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ999999999999)}@gmail.com

Here
4: the count of the generating random number